# Ruby on rails 5.1 upgrade, cannot name index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, migration, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm upgrading to rails 5.1 but my migrations are failing due to an index name being too long.

Error:

```
ArgumentError: Index name 'index_mailboxer_notifications_on_notified_object_type_and_notified_object_id' on table 'mailboxer_notifications' is too long; the limit is 63 characters
```

The index name automatically gets created, but I should be able to name it by using the `name:` command.

Migration.rb

```
add_index :mailboxer_notifications, [:notified_object_id, :notified_object_type],
    name: 'index_mailboxer_notifications_on_notified_object_id_and_type'
```

But the `name:` command seems to be getting ignored. Has this changed in rails 5.1? Is there any other way to name the index?

Answer (score 0):

In case index name is too long and migration is failed to run, it should not create any index.

Try drop index on `notified_object_id, notified_object_type` columns if it is exists and run migration with index name again.